# How long are you considered 'new'?

Tags: support

On Stack Overflow, when you are new, you have a message under your questions and answers telling the user replying not to go too hard because the person is new - when does the message get removed? (Does it get removed when you gain enough reputation or when you have been on Stack Overflow for a certain amount of time?)